# Javascript Function activates before button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

If requirements are met when you click the button it will display a count down timer. Problem is it displays the countdown timer BEFORE you even click the button. I'm not sure what I'm overlooking.

```
 <input id="upgrade" type="button" value="Upgrade" onclick="timer();" />
 <br><br><br><br>
 <p id="countdown_timer"></p>

<script>
    function display_timer(){
        document.getElementById("countdown_timer").innerHTML = "<span id='countdown' class='timer'></span>";
    }
</script>

<script>
    var currently_upgrading = 0;
    var current_ore         = 398;
    var current_crystal     = 398;
    var upgradeTime  = 172801;
    var seconds      = upgradeTime;

    function timer() {
        if(currently_upgrading == 1){alert('You are already upgrading a module.');return;}
        if(current_ore <= 299){alert('You need more ore.');return;}
        if(current_crystal <= 299){alert('You need more crystal.');return;}

        display_timer();
        var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
        var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
        var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
        var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Your timer() setinterval calls the display_timer()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the last lines of `timer()` to be like this:

```
    if (seconds == 0) {
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
    } else {
        seconds--;
        setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    }
```

and remove the `setInterval` line.

Speaking generally, `setTimeout` is much preferred to `setInterval`, because it doesn't require a managed state (`countdownTimer` in your example) and is far more flexible.

Also note that passing a string as in `setTimeout('timer()', 1000)` is obsolete, just pass a function: `setTimeout(timer, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `countdownTimer` variable into your `timer()` function.

Comment: So, each time the function is called, it will set a new interval? I don't think this is correct.

Comment: @georg I only mentioned the solution to work with OP's code. However, yes, you are totally right.

Comment: Actually that caused the timer to go all nuts and crash the browser eventually! lol  The countdown instead of dropping in increments of 1 kept doubling itself so 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128, crash..

Comment: I just used georg's method and it works fine :) Thanks alot guys.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

will execute 1 second after the page loads as well as on the button click and this calls the `display_timer` function.

Answer (score 1):

you have called it in setInterval function, so it will starts immediately , because setInterval function runs after page loads and not on click and setInterval uses your function